# How would an object bounce if you throw it into a corner directly

Tags: game-physics, physics-engine

I don't think you can do this in real life because of engineering issues. But in a physics engine, if you throw a ball into a corner(both inwards and outwards). How would the object bounces, directly back, left, right, or just glitches out?

Comment: why would you not be able to throw a ball in a corner in real life? *Takes a ball, throws it in a corner* Looks like my reality is still working, how about yours?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we are in the Z plane with two walls, the ball would bounce right back as we have two reflections with a 45° incidence angle causing a movement change of +90° respectively.

A 'direct hit' would just result in the brown arrow being infinitely short.

[image]

This applies in dimension of you treat a corner as the conjunction point of N perpendicular walls.